# Is there any REAL Skype alternative where I can add my Skype friends (without asking them to join to a new app)?

Tags: 12.04, skype, webcam, pidgin

I have installed Skype but, despite the recent updates, it still seems to have bugs. Anyway, I am looking for an alternative for it, and I saw from internet that there are plenty of Open Source alternatives to Skype: Ekiga, Linphone. Blink, Jitsi, Empathy so on.

Anyway, I did not installed and tried any of those, except for Empathy which looks promising but it was a big disappointment to me and I will unistall it.

So, the idea is: What other app should I use in order to keep contact with my Skype friends? I don't wont to install, let's say, Ekiga, and then ask my friends to create IDs on Ekiga. I don't think is polite from my part to ask/force people to change their software just because it doesn't fit my taste.

As a Windows user, I did used Yahoo Messenger and Gtalk app. Now, when I'm on Linux, I use Pidgin to chat with my friends from both these accounts. Well, I need something like Pidgin, but for Skype. I need an app which I can use with my Skype ID and I can add my Skype friends to it, without having to ask them to join the new app. In extremis, I am willing to create an ID for the new app, but I still need to add my Skype friends to it in the conditions mentioned above.

Is there any such app where I can import my Skype friends (just like I did with my YM and Gtalk friends in Pidgin)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is: no, only skype can mannage skype accounts.

Also Pidgin is a client not a server, you did not import your friends. If you are interested in using Skype in Pidgin you can go to the [third party plugin](https://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins) site and check for the Skype IM plugin.

Notice that for skype buddies to show in Pidgin you will need to run both skype and pidgin at the same time and that this functionality might stop working in the future due to api changes in skype that will, if you insist in using it, "force" you to keep an old version of skype installed with all the issues involved.

http://code.google.com/p/skype4pidgin/

Comment: By the way, the OP can still wait for the new Microsoft Skype API to come out... (that's a nice joke, isn't it ?)

Comment: @xangua "Importing friends", "adding friends", whatever! :-) I am aware of the fact that I might not use the terminology properly. Anyway, it is too bad that, in the long list of Open Source alternatives to Skype, there is none that can be used as replacement to Skype. Thank you for your detailed answer and for the third party plugin suggested. I'll give it a try although the ide of having two apps running in the same time is not very enchanting/attractive and defies logic. But, if there isn't any other solution, I guess I'll have to give this a try...

Comment: @JohnWHSmith What is OP?

Comment: @CristianaNicolae OP means the Original Poster of the question, which would be you in this case. :)

Comment: Thanks @Merri! Its good to know! I really didn't know about this!

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** Just log into https://web.skype.com/ and leave it open.

**Long answer:** Skype has closed source, closed/obfuscated protocol, spyware crap, full of ads, buggy, bloatware, resource intensive and here comes the worst: ALL the things you ever say/do/send will be stored in their data centers forever without the possibility of deletion (that's what it actually says in their TOS) All your history will be always there and protected only by a exploitable (if you are a target) password. [Verification needed]

The above reasons are more than enough to say "*Nobody* should use Skype ever", but you might ask: Why they are still alive and are the number one IM!? The answer is simple: because a lot of people are ignorant (on technical details and implications of their actions) and are only interested of end-user experience/convenience - that's the main reason we are *forced* to use this kind of software, because work, friends, family, don't know or care to use something open source, open protocol like SIP which IMO is way better.